# Single quote in JSON return from MySQL gets changed to special character when returned to Flutter call

Tags: node.js, flutter

I am facing an issue, where a single quote/apostrophe that is in a string and then sent to a nodejs rest api and then is inserted into a JSON field in MySQL, when I get the same JSON and return to a call made from Flutter, the JSON looks right when I curl, it also looks right when I print it out.  I use restify and `res.json(json)`, when flutter gets the `response.body` the single quote is now some special character "a with a shift 6 over the top".  I have tried replace, stringify but do not understand why it is changed, it does not happen on the way out which makes me think its flutter, but can not find how or how to handle it.

Anyone with ideas would be great, let me know any code you want to see.

```
{"oid":1,"pid":1,"sub":"Re: Sarah Doe","prid":"1","oname":"Referring Doctor","pname":"Amar Patel","msgkey":"d47f6e81-8c8e-4209-a073-03a8d2e79356","pgrpid":"1","sender":"o","message":"This is to test the apostrophe that can’t be used","fcmtoken":null,"receiver":"p","sendname":"Referring Doctor","submitdate":"2017-11-06 05:24:25.015089","receivename":"Amar Patel","referralname":"Sarah Doe"}
```

It never changes, it always looks like this, I have tried to

```
replace("'","\'")
```

I have also tried

```
replace(/\'/g, '"')
```

This is code in one of its many iterations

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                //console.log('****RESULT****CHAT***: ', results[i].chat);
                var myrecord = results[i].chat;
                //console.log('MYRECORD: '+myrecord);
                //console.log('MYRECORD-STRING: '+JSON.stringify(myrecord));
                var json = myrecord.replace(/\'/g, '"');
                //console.log('JSON-REPLACE: '+json);
                myjson.push(JSON.parse(json));

            }
```

Nothing seems to affect the single quote that is in the message node.

Comment: Can you please add the affected part of the JSON to your question (how it looks before and after conversion)?

Comment: Code has been added

Comment: There are a lot of components involved (db, server, client). It's necessary to find out what step causes the `'` to become that weird character.

Comment: I agree, if you do a curl to this curl http://loop-dev.clinicalsoftworks.com/csapi/getmessages/1/d47f6e81-8c8e-4209-a073-03a8d2e79356, you will see that the return looks fine with the ', but when flutter gets the response.body it has the character, so not sure if its flutter that is doing it, but since a curl returns the correct JSON, hard to find that its nodejs.  Not sure why though I never get it to replace with escape character.

Comment: Is there any difference in the sent/received headers? Like charset for example?

Comment: Not that I can see.  I send content-type as application/json and it is returned as well the same.  The request does show Utf8Codec and encoding from the flutter side, but its not a header per se, its just in the request object when I debug on it.

Comment: The server where you request the JSON from is not by any chance available publicly?

Comment: yes, you can curl it curl http://loop-dev.clinicalsoftworks.com/csapi/getmessages/1/d47f6e81-8c8e-4209-a073-03a8d2e79356

Comment: Interesting, when I pull it up in a browser it shows the weird character, but a curl does not.

Comment: I just opened the link in the browser amd got `canâ€™t`. Either curl send different headers or by other means interprets the response differently. Flutter seems to have the same behavior as the browser.

Comment: I saw that, but if you look in developers tools, that is not what it gets, its just how its displayed for some reason.  The raw response has the single quote.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I tthink it's a character that looks like a single quote but is actually a different character or iz's an encoding issue utf8/utf16 mismatch or similar.

Comment: Thats interesting, it happens on my mac and on an iOS device, but just tested it on my android and actually got an error trying to submit, which means its something weird with the Apple stuff or something.  I will see what I can find.

Comment: I've seen "curly quotes" show up weird in data.

Comment: I think your replace code isn't replacing anything because you're not replacing the correct character. Try replacing ’ by '

Comment: your correct, because the character sent via the iOS phone and simulator is not really a single quote.  Thats where I am trying to figure out why now.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to iOS 11 and the addition of smart punctuation.  Because of that a curly quote is sent and not a true single quote.  Unfortunately it is not exposed to turn it off, right now you have to choose a url or email keyboard where it is turned off.